# How to restrict image rotation after capturing image from camera

Tags: android, file, camera, image-rotation, autorotate

In my application captured image rotated automatically in samsung specific device.
I want to restrict this. For this I used ExifInterface concept also,but no luck,

Anyone help me!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using default camera app to capture image? If so, you can't prevent that from happening but after receiving the image you can use exifintrface to rotate it to correct angle. There might be some issues in your exifinterface implementation. Share your code

Comment: The question is unclear. Please post the relevant piece of code that you tried.

Comment: I made a silly mistake in my code. I Forget to add config change code in my manifest file,because of that one issue is resolved.sorry if this question disturbs anyone .

Comment: Can you please share the change you made!!